# MongoDB not working with PHP on WAMP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have been having trouble with getting MongoDB and php working together:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\wamp\www\mongoDBTest\index.php on line 6
```

Here are my details:

- system: Windows NT LAPBTN1894 6.1 build 7600 (Windows 7 Enterprise Edition) AMD64
- Architecture: x64
- Apache/PHP: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 thread safe
- Compiler: MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
- MongoDB: 2.4.5

MongoDB works fine on it's own and I have created the data/db folder.

I have tried adding php_mongo.dll to my php ext folder using the file "php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll" and then renaming it and adding the relevent extension in the php.ini file.

I also know about this site and not found anything useful
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

Comment: When you run `phpinfo()`, do you see any entries dealing with the mongo extension?

Comment: nope, it's like it knows nothing about it

Comment: [Looks like you’ll have to teach PHP about Mongo then.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php)

Comment: Can you link the pertinent areas of index.php? It can't find a php class. Did you add the class to index.php?

Comment: @Paul As far as I know there is no `Mongo` class, but there is a `MongoClient` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing you have restarted WAMP after changing the php.ini extensions.
At first, try to add the MongoDB in your ENVIRONMENT PATH and restart computer (you would be surprised by the amount of problems the restart does solve).

When changing the php.ini try either to do not change the DLL name, and add it the way you downloaded it.

[You can check some of this tips in detail clicking here.](http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way)

Comment: That was perfect, exactly what I needed. I uninstalled WAMP and MongoDB and re-installed using that guide and it works great now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Watch this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894906/mongodb-php-driver-installation-issue-on-wamp

Answer (score 0):

Thats becasue the mongoDB extension does nto come with WAMP by default.

You have to install it yourself,

[here is a starter for 10](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows)

Second try:

When you run the wamp home page and then phpinfo(), does mongoDB show up in the installed list?

Secondly can you run a command window and cd into \wamp\bin\php\php5.4.x
And run

```
php.exe -i
```

Then check

```
Compiler => ??????????
Architecture => ???
```

Of course it might be worth checking that you are trying to instantiate the correct object.
According to the manual this is the way its should be done.

```
$connection = new MongoClient(); // connects to localhost:27017
$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://example.com" ); // connect to a remote host (default port: 27017)
$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://example.com:65432" ); // connect to a remote host at a given port
```

Comment: Did you read the question? The link you provided was already mentioned.

Comment: @Lix Obviously not! Woops

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to achieve but I dont seem to be able to find the correct extension

Comment: @Lix Let me try and redeem myself.

Comment: @rig - if you want more info from the OP, you should do so in the form of comments. Please don't use answers to request more information. Note the text on the button - `"Post Your Answer"`

Comment: @Lix I am not requesting info I am suggesting ways (s)he can find out for sure that they are running what they think they are running.