# MongoDb PHP driver installation issue on wamp

Tags: php, mongodb, wampserver

I have php of version 5.5.12 and wamp version 2.4.9 and PHP Extension Build as API20121212,TS,VC11 . I am using this dll 'php_mongo-1.5.5-5.5-vc11.dll' (renamed to php_mongo) but still when i restart my all services mongo db is not displaying on phpinfo().Any pointer where m i going wrong ?

Comment: Try downloading the PHP extension from here `http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo` and make sure you pick the Thread Safe (TS) version and also make sure you download the 32 or 64 bit version to match your wampserver install.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: you have not included libsasl.dll file correctly. check my answer I have described it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have never used MONGO, but I was interested to see if there where problems using it with WAMPServer so I did a quick install to prove it shoud work, **and it does**.

Here is a list of what I did, I hope it helps you work out what you may have done wrong.

First you have to download the Mongo Database manager itself and install it.
Download from `https://www.mongodb.org/downloads`

Updated Aug 2019: 
[Download from here now](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)

So you can place the software yourself I would download the ZIP and NOT the .MSI this way you dont get your system messed with by the .msi developer and what they think should be done to your system and you are in complete control.

Download the 32bit or 64 bit version to match your OS and WampServer(32/64) version you are running.

Now the Install is just a case of extracting the files from the zip and placing them somewhere on your system. I suggest :-

Copy the `bin` folder from the extract to `c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z` ( x.y.z to match the version of mongo you downloaded).

Create a data folder under that folder, so `c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z\data`
Create a data folder for your first database under that folder, so `\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z\data\db`

Create a config file for mongo in `c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z\mongod.cfg` and add as a minimum these parameter :-

**NOTE:** these are just params that will get it running, NOT A DEFINITIVE SET OF PARAMETERS!

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "c:/wamp/logs/mongod.log"
  logAppend: true
  timeStampFormat: iso8601-local

net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

storage:
  dbPath: "c:/wamp/bin/mongo/mongo2.6.6/data"
  directoryPerDB: true
```

Now if you want to have mongodb running as a service create a command file like so in the `C:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z` folder :-

Filename = install_service.cmd

```
mongod.exe --config "c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongo2.6.6\mongod.cfg" --install --serviceName wampmongodb --serviceDisplayName wampmongodb
sc config wampmongodb start= demand
```

*The space between `start=` and `demand` is required, not a typo*

For completeness also create an uninstall file :-

Filename = uninstall_service.cmd

```
mongod.exe --remove --serviceName wampmongodb
```

Now create 2 command files to start and stop your mongodb instance

Filename = start_mongo.cmd

```
net start wampmongodb
```

Filename = stop_mongo.cmd

```
net stop wampmongodb
```

Now start a command window using (Run as Administrator) and use these command files to install and start your MONGODB Server

```
CD \wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z
#Install MONGO as a service
install_service
#Start the service
start_mongo
```

Now check the `c:\wamp\logs` folder and make sure there are no errors reported in the mongod.log file

While still in the command window, check that mongo is running by trying a few simple commands
Use the instructions here `http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/` to prove that it is all working.

**NOW ADD THE PHP Extension**

Download from 'http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo'

Select the version you want and click the Windows icon with the word DLL beside it, in the 'Downloads' column.

This will take you to the download page for that version of the MONGO PHP extension.

You should now select the download link that matches the version of the MONGO extension you want, and the matching (x86) for 32bit WAMPServer installs or (x64) for 64bit WAMPServer installs.

You must click the 'DLL' link otherwise you will get a unix/linux source code.

**Remember you must match the 32 or 64 bit to the version of WAMPServer you downloaded**

So if you are running Windows 64bit but installed WAMPServer 32bit you need the 32bit version of the MONGO extension.

Also remember that you need the **Thread Safe** version **(TS)** to run with WAMPServer's Apache configuration.

Extract the zip file, and copy `php_mongo.dll` to your PHP folder eg `C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\ext`

Edit your php.ini file to add the new extension.
To use Mongo with your web server (Apache) use the wampmanager menus to edit php.ini i.e.

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

and add this line after all the other extension lines

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

To use mongo with scripts run from the command line (PHP CLI) edit `C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini` and add the extension line again in there.

Start Wampmanager. Or Restart the Apache service.
This should refresh WAMPServers config and pick up the new PHP extension, if not do this when wampmanager is running:-

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service
```

Run localhost by :-

```
wampmanager -> localhost
```

and then click on the phpinfo() link on the homepage.

You should now see a section entitled 'mongo' with some configuration options listed. If you do the PHP MONGO extension is active.

**IMPORTANT**

If you are running Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7 you may have to install this HotFix to resolve an issue with Memory Mapped Files.
Request it from here `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2731284/en-us`. You have to ask for it, and then they send you an email telling you where it can be downloaded from.

The link they gave me was `http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows 7/Windows Server2008 R2 SP1/sp2/Fix405791/7600/free/451412_intl_i386_zip.exe`

However I did not need to install it to get to the stage where MONGO was installed and running simple tests from the command line AND through Apache and PHP.

Comment: How to download Mongo Database manager? This link doesn't work : https://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Comment: Well I googled it and found [this new location](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)

Answer (score 17):

first of all you have to download the latest mongo dll files from 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html
unzip the downloaded file and you will see a bunch of files like this:
[image]

now it is time to decide which dll file you have to use.
open your phpinfo() and search for word **compiler**. you will see sth like this:
[image]
so now according to my compiler version (MSVC11) I have to choose file with **vc11** word inside their name. according to my PHP version which is 5.5.12 I have to choose file with word **5.5** inside their name.
now search for word **thread safety** in your phpinfo 
[image]

and if it was enabled, it means that you have to choose file that doesn't have word **nts** inside their name but if your thread safety was disabled then you need to choose file with word **nts** inside their name.
now according to your installation architecture you may choose files with **x86_64** inside their name.
after choosing the appropriate dll file, rename it to **php_mongo.dll** and copy paste it to your php extensions directory which is mostly located at
**C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext** 
now open your php.ini file and add this at the end of it.
**extension=php_mongo.dll** 
according to
 http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php 
for installing mongo on windows, you have to also include **libsasl.dll** in your system PATH.
**libsasl.dll** file is mostly located at 
**C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12** 

 add this path to your system PATH.
reboot your wamp, refresh your phpinfo page and you should see sth like this:
[image]
which means that you have installed mongo correctly. :)

Comment: No one  mentioned about missing dll, so this helped my issue to fix, that's why +1 .

Comment: I did all the steps same but mongo does not show @Salar. Also, I am getting error MongoClient not found. I am using php

Comment: You, sir, saved my life. Any tutorial I found wasn't as simple and effective as this. +1!

Comment: i do that for php 7 .((MongoDB extension version 1.4.2)) i can see on phpinfo..But when run php -m i have not it on list

Answer (score 1):

If you still facing the problem follow bellow two rules:

- Make sure you downloaded drivers from
  http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo
- Try version 1.5.1 drivers (When I
  am writing this the latest driver version is 1.6.8 but 1.6.8 to 1.5.5 nothing is worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Have you entered the .dll in your php.ini file (properly)?

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Updates for PHP 7 version.
As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-language-php) we have to download **mongodb-1.2**. You can download it from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.2.9/windows) based on your PHP version.