# MpngoDB installation error with localhost Xampp

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

[image]

i have installed wampserver 32 bit, and i have added php_mongo.dll. php_mongo.dll showing in the wampserver extension list. but when i go through the following code to check the services its showing same error msg.

```
echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n"; 
echo extension_loaded("mysql") ? " mysql loaded\n" : " mysql not
```

Showing

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Comment: I assume you installed and tested MONGODB 32 bit as well

Comment: Is this post any use to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894906/mongodb-php-driver-installation-issue-on-wamp/27940069#27940069

Comment: Yes, but again I am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you run the Mongo test from the command line as part of your MongoDB installation testing?

Comment: Yes i have installed mongo in my c Drive and i have already tested it with command line, its working for me but i am facing froblem with wamp.

Comment: Now I have uninstalled WAMP and then i have installed XAMP and go through this http://devzone.co.in/configure-mongodb-php-windows-xampp-5-simple-steps/. Now Mongo  is showing in my phpinfo. I think its resolve